# Full local customisation for html template and css theme/hightlighting

Tags: templates, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I am currently exploring the R Markdown configurations and the possibilities for the HTML output. My goal is to have a local html template as well as a local css theme file which behaves exactly the same as if I would select theme/highlight options in in the yaml configurations.

I used the following configuration:

```
output:
  html_document:
    theme: united
    highlight: tango
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 3
    toc_float: # set to false if you do no want a floating toc
    collapsed: true
    smooth_scroll: true
```

I now want to be able to customize the HTML structure and the CSS by my own. I started with the HTML template as follows:

Downloaded the standard [pandoc HTML5 template](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.html5) and copied it into a local `template.html` file. I changed my configuration to

```
output:
  html_document:
    template: template.html
    theme: united
    highlight: tango
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 3
    toc_float: # set to false if you do no want a floating toc
    collapsed: true
    smooth_scroll: true
```

There are several problems arizing:

- the TOC is not shown anymore
- the rendered HTML design of the output changed, i.e. I have no margin at all - all javascript functionality is gone, so no DT support, no tabs, no scrolling etc.

My question is: How can I achive the exactly same design and functionality I had before with my configuration but having the template/theme/highlight files stored locally? (So a template.html and a styles.css and all the needed JS files)

Let me know if I need to give further details. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pandoc default you linked to is not the default used in `rmarkdown`.  That one is stored in `system.file("rmd/h/default.html", pkg = "rmarkdown")`, and a current version is online here: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/inst/rmd/h/default.html.

You should also study the source to `rmarkdown::html_document` if you decide to modify the default template.  You'll also have to make some other changes if `template != "default"`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint with the correct template - when using the suggested from above all works as expected and I can make changes to the HTML. Can you please ellaborate on your second paragraph? What do you mean exactly when `template != "default"`? Can you recommend some literature on that? Thanks so much!

Comment: Just the source to `rmarkdown::html_document`.  `"default"` is the default value for the `template` argument, and I see two tests for it in the source.